# how to change color for elbow connectors in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

Below code is giving me an error stating specified value is out of range.

```
Sub Green()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Elbow Connector 62").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbGreen
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's two options - one with a variable and one without. You might need to change the 2 to a 62.

```
Sub Macro1()

    ActiveSheet.shapes.Range(Array("Elbow Connector 2")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
End Sub



Sub shapes()

Dim s As ShapeRange

Set s = ActiveSheet.shapes.Range(Array("elbow connector 2"))

    With s
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```